# JS - Combining an arrays elements with multiple other array's elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to combine multiple arrays elements into a single array. 
 
To put it in better perspective let's say I have 3 arrays that look like this

```
array1 = ['test']
array2 = ['foo', 'foo_1', 'foo_2']
array3 = ['bar']
```

In the end I need a single array that looks like this.

```
finalArray = ['test.foo.bar', 'test.foo_1.bar', 'test.foo_2.bar'].
```

Each array might have different sizes and lengths. But the idea is the same. Kinda like a tree with each array being a branch of the other when combining.

Any help with this would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: this looks like a form of brace expansion. there's an npm package that does something similar: https://github.com/juliangruber/brace-expansion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Array.map`, you can map item by item from first array to third array.

```js
const array1 = ['test'];
const array2 = ['foo', 'foo_1', 'foo_2'];
const array3 = ['bar'];

const result = array1.map((item1) => array2.map((item2) => `${item1}.${item2}`))
  .flat()
  .map((item) => array3.map((item3) => `${item}.${item3}`))
  .flat();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you pls approve my answer if it works well?